# Docker CMD not executing, program not running

Tags: python, docker, data-science

So I have a python project for which I have a Dockerfile, but the problem is for some magical reason when I build the docker image and then run it I don't see the result of the code I would see if I just ran it normally on pycharm or on the console, anyone knows why this happens? Its so odd.

```
FROM python:3.8-slim-buster
WORKDIR /app
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
COPY . /app
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
CMD ["python3","main.py"]
```

The requirements.txt file is where I store all the packages that need to be installed in order to my program work.

Comment: What *does* happen when you run it? Do you get an error message? Unexpected output? Some other behavior?

Comment: Nop! The program just don't run! But no errors

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You copy your application to wrong path.

Since you use `WORKDIR` you need to know (from the formal [site](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#workdir)):

> The WORKDIR instruction sets the working directory for any RUN, CMD, ENTRYPOINT, COPY and ADD instructions that follow it in the Dockerfile

This means that your `COPY . /app` copy your application into `/app/app`, but when you write `CMD ["python3","main.py"]` this command will execute in `/app`. I believe the `main.py` file is not there, but in `/app/app`.

To fix it you need to change `COPY . /app` to `COPY . .`

Comment: Thanks for the help ! However I did this and its still not working

Comment: When you say "I don't see the result of the code" what do you mean?

Comment: I have come to the conclusion its because im trying to change a sqlite3 database outside of the container, is there any solution for this ?

Comment: If the right-hand side of `COPY` is an absolute path, it's used as-is.  A relative directory `COPY . ./app` would be interpreted relative to `WORKDIR`.

Comment: @Johny, If I understand you correctly, the code running in your container should change the data in sqlite2 DB outside of the container?

Comment: Since the DB in on your host, I think you need to run the container on the same network of your host so add `--network=host` to your `docker run` command and from the shell of the container do some trials until you find the correct way to interact with your DB